# Jquery/Javascript looping div scroller

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make 5 divs that loop in and out forever. The divs will have classes "text1" "text2" "text3" etc. Is there anything wrong with this code? It doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var num = 1
    while(num =< 5) {
        $('.text' + num).fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut()
        var num = num ++i

        if(num == 5) {
            var num = 1
        }
        else{
            var num = num
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you want them all to fade in and out at the same time, or one after the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of a callback function inside the `fadeOut` method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function fader(i) {
        $('div.text' + i).fadeIn('slow')
            .delay(4000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
                fader(i % 5 + 1);
            });
    }

    fader(1);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/NXuVM/2/

Answer (score 2):

That will loop infinitely. `.delay` does not pause the execution, it just sets up a function to be called later. Your code sets up `fadeOut` to be called an infinite number of times, 4 seconds later.

You want `setInterval` instead:

```
<div class="textContainer">
    <div>Text 1</div>
    <div>Text 2</div>
    <div>Text 3</div>
    <div>Text 4</div>
    <div>Text 5</div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    var divs = $('.textContainer div');
    setInterval(function() {
        divs.eq(i).fadeOut();
        i = (i + 1) % divs.length;
        divs.eq(i).fadeIn();
    }, 4000);
});
```

Comment: Eric, thanks for your help, I inserted both your html and scripts into my page and it doesn't seem to work though

Comment: @A_funs: Fixed. I was using `[i]` instead of `.eq(i)`

Comment: Thanks again Eric, you get an honorable mention! Your code did work in the end but mblase75's was more what i was looking for